# C# SQL SUM value to a label

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

I currently have a DataGridView which displays all the item. I would like to sum all the prices in the price column and then reflect the total in a label, 'TotalValueLabel'. What's wrong with my statement?

```
        string query = "SELECT SUM (Price) FROM Bill";
        OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, DBconn);
        DataTable source = new DataTable();
        dAdapter.Fill(source);
        TotalValueLabel.Text = source.ToString();
```

Comment: You should probably tell us what is going wrong in your example. Does it crash? Does it display anything?

Comment: it doesn't display anything in the label when the form loads

Comment: I would normally write TotalValueLabel.Text = source.Rows[0][0].ToString();

Comment: Thanks Paul, that worked a treat! Could you explain to me what the Rows[0][0] are?

Comment: Rows[0] means first row of the data table, The second index accesses the row columns collection - returns the value of the first column. So Rows[1][5] would be the 6th column value of the 2nd row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your source is a DataTable so "`source.ToString()`" will not give you your result,

Try "`source.Rows[0][0].ToString();`".

DataTable object contains a list of DataRow objects which hold values for each row of your query result.

In your case however you might not need this. If you are looking for a single value you should use [IDbCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) and call `ExecuteScalar()`. This will return the **first value** of the **first row** of your results.

Also try calling `Dispose()` on objects that implement [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx) (like dbadapter, command, connection).

```
string query = "SELECT SUM (Price) FROM Bill";
using (System.Data.IDbCommand command = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, DBconn))
{
   object result = command.ExecuteScalar();
   TotalValueLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works as Paul also suggested earlier. I have a question though, how can i display the result in currency format?

Comment: Then first convert the result to int and use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx .

Comment: TotalValueLabel.Text = source.Rows[0][0].ToString("C"); doesn't seem to be working

Comment: source.Rows[0][0] returns an object. ToString with formatting parameter works on numeric data such as int, decimal, etc. So convert source.Rows[0][0] object to int, then call ToString("C").

Answer (score 2):

DataTable is overkill for single value retrieval, besides your not even accessing the value correctly, better way is to use execute scalar:

```
var query = "SELECT SUM (Price) FROM Bill";
using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, DBcon))
{
    TotalValueLabel.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. May i know the difference between using a datatable and executescalar?

Comment: http://www.nigelwhitworth.com/VB/whatisthedifferencebetweenexecutereaderexecutescalarexecutexmlreaderandexecutenonquerydafillobjdt.php