# C# SQL AVG to a Text box

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a query that gets me the correct info. I am unsure of how to display the data from that query on a web page in a TextBox.

Yes, I have seen this: [C# SQL SUM value to a label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978137/c-sharp-sql-sum-value-to-a-label/4978186#4978186).

It did not help, even after searching what that user was doing. I really am not sure what all I need to do, though it looks like a few lines of code solves the trick. I really lack experience with things like this.

Thus far, I have the text box, `avgRating`. I have `SqlDataSource2`. Which runs the query that gets the correct data. I am just unsure of where to go from there.

I DID try the above method, but it was a little over my head. Does anyone have an idea for me to run with?

Note: It does not necessarily need to be a a text box. If it is more easily feasible to perform this using another GridView or something, please let me know. I am as new as they come.

Comment: Whats the exact problem your running into, if we could see your code it might help us help you.

Comment: Sure. My code is 100% incorrect, though. I don't know how to code this, whatsoever...

        string query = "SELECT AVG (courseRating) FROM Review_tbl";
        SqlDataSource adapter = new SqlDataSource();
        adapter.Fill(source);
        avgRating.Text = source.Rows[0][0].ToString();

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of codes available, this is how I do it. I guess this is what you are asking:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbConnection oCon = new OleDbConnection();
oCon.ConnectionString = _connStr;
oCon.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT AVG (courseRating) FROM Review_tbl", oCon);
da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
da.Fill(dt);
oCon.Close();

string value = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();

Textbox1.Text = value;
```

Comment: It says oCon, _connStr, and da are a 'field' but used as a 'type' .. Any idea?

Comment: I dont know how you used it but _conn is COnnection string and da is Data Adapter ..