# Collect data and display the data in a column label

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sqlcommand

How can I sum a column to the table without dataGridView and i'm using sql command method  And my database is in SQL server 2008.
I like [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978137/c-sharp-sql-sum-value-to-a-label)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the `DataTable` and sum the field you like.

You can try something like this one,

```
string query = "SELECT Price FROM Bill";
OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, DBconn);
DataTable dtSource = new DataTable();
dAdapter.Fill(dtSource);
int colSum =0;
foreach (DataRow dr in dtSource .Rows)  
{                     
    colSum += Convert.ToInt32(dr["Price"]);
}
TotalValueLabel.Text = colSum.ToString();
```

For multiplication, you can try something like this,

```
string query = "SELECT Qty,Price FROM Bill";
OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, DBconn);
DataTable dtSource = new DataTable();
dAdapter.Fill(dtSource);
dtSource.Columns.Add("3rdColumn");
foreach (DataRow dr in dtSource .Rows)  
{                     
  dr["3rdColumn"]= Convert.ToInt32(dr["Qty"]) * Convert.ToInt32(dr["Price"]);
}
```

Comment: You can use something like this,

`foreach (DataRow dr in dtSource .Rows)
 {                
    colSum += Convert.ToInt32(dr["colValue"]);                
 }`

Comment: thank:I did not notice too much of your code: Please enter the code easier to give

Comment: Thank you dear friends: I tried your code: If the problem was: I will tell you

Comment: Hello dear friend, your code will work correctly: Thank you. 
Just one question: How do I multiply columns with the same code? 
Is there such a way? 
Thank

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly do you mean by 'multiply'?

Comment: Thank you dear friend 
I mean is there anything else i want the first column in a two-column multiplication result is saved in the third column: 
The query and update commands: its the same code into a website but I do not know why his C # How do I order? 
Please Help! 

UPDATE SALES SET totalcost=quantity*costperunit

Thank

Comment: Thank you, dear friend, but your code does not work! 
Collect your code worked, but it did not work 
What is the problem??

Comment: I wrote the code exactly does and does not work but no error 
It is strange 
Do you know any other way? 
Do you know any other coding style but it sqlcommand

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Data;    

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Price from PriceList", connection);
sda.Fill(dt);
int sum=Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("sum(Price)",""));
Label1.Text=sum.ToString();
```

Comment: thank guys
but I do'nt know linq !!!
I just know ado.net(sql command)
i'am very beginner: please help me!!!!
thanks

Comment: Question: Please help 
The last line 
What should I write the query? 
Like this 
query = "SELECT SUM (Price) FROM Bill"; 
Or 
To your code. 
Thank you dear friend. 
Good Luck.

Comment: In SqlDataAdapter write the query. The result set was filled in Datatable. Based on the column name get the sum. I modified the answer check it

Comment: Thank you dear friend 
Sorry 
One other question. 
How can I compare or Attached the output value to the label 
Please write the full code!
i am beginner

thank

Comment: While this may answer the question, can you provide any commentary as to what the code is doing rather than just posting a code sample?

Comment: friends:Please explain more about your code: Thanks

Comment: Hello dear friend, your code will work correctly as code BAdmin: Thank you. 
Just one question: How do I multiply columns with the same code? 
Is there such a way? 
Sorry for the repeat question! 
Thank

Comment: hi       Please put your code into a multiplication operation 
Thank