# How to get value of under a column and total of them

Tags: c#

I want to get values under of "Column B" and total of these numbers but i couldnt figure out how to do it i know these codes really bad im sorry about that im new to c#

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | 30 |
| Cell 3 | 40 |

here is my code

```
void Columns()
{
    conn.Open();
    string sql5 = "SELECT *FROM musteriler";
    using (cmd = new SqlCommand(sql5, conn))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader columns = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            decimal total = 0.0m;
            while (columns.Read())
            {
                for (int f = 0; f < columns.FieldCount; f++)
                {
                    total += columns.GetDecimal(f);
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show(total.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

i have tried with string builder but it didnt work

```
            void ColumnsExecuter()
            {
                conn.Open();
                string sql5 = "SELECT *FROM musteriler";
                using (cmd = new SqlCommand(sql5, conn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader columns = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        while (columns.Read())
                        {
                            if (sb.Length > 0)
                                sb.Append(",");
                            sb.Append(Convert.ToInt32(columns["Teklif"]));
                        }
                        int a = int.Parse(sb.ToString());
                        var res = new List<int>();
                        res.Add(a);
                        double toplam = 0;  
                        for (int i = 0; i < res.Count; i++)
                        {
                            toplam+= Convert.ToDouble(res[i]);  
                        }
```

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978137/c-sharp-sql-sum-value-to-a-label

Answer (score 0):

Change "SELECT *FROM musteriler" to "SELECT ColumnB FROM musteriler"

Answer (score 0):

Use a DataAdapter

```
           using (cmd = new SqlCommand(sql5, conn))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);

                foreach(DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
                {
                    int total = row.ItemArray.Sum(x => (int)x);
                    Console.WriteLine(total);
                }

            }
```